# What is BeginReceive(Byte(), Int32, Int32, SocketFlags, AsyncCallback, Object) and callback method in socket?

Tags: c#, vb.net, sockets

I am so new in socket programming. So, recently I am assigned to a task in socket programming using vb.net to find out why this program is allocating almost 20GB of the physical memory. But as I don't have proper knowledge in Socket so I am quite stuck inside. I have found that `BeginReceive()` method and `EndReceive()` method as callback is in the program and when I googled for these I found some information that `EndReceive()` should be called for callback. So, my question is:

1. Do I need to call the `EndReceive()` method after `BeginReceive()` every time  to clear the buffer so that the memory allocation becomes clear?
2. I would really appreciate if someone explain in simple words what does really  mean by `BeginReceive()` and `EndReceive()`?

Update: Please check the below code I found in the project:

```
Public Sub Receive(ByVal client As Socket)

      Dim state As New StateObject
    state.workSocket = client


    Try
        If m_clientSocket.Connected Then

            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReceiveCallback), state)
        Else
            Connect()
        End If

    Catch se As SocketException
        logstr = se.Message
        write_log(logstr, "Receive", "Receive")
    End Try
End Sub


 Public Sub ReceiveCallback(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)


    Dim state As StateObject = CType(ar.AsyncState, StateObject)
    Dim client As Socket = state.workSocket
    Dim receiveData As String = ""
    Dim sendData As String = ""

    Dim bytesRead As Integer = client.EndReceive(ar)

    If bytesRead > 0 Then

        state.sb.Append(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead))

        client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReceiveCallback), state)      

        receiveData = state.sb.ToString()

        Me.lsBulk.Items.Insert(0, receiveData)
        sendData = getReply(receiveData)
        write_log(Now.ToString & " : " & receiveData & vbCrLf, "bytesRead", "bytesRead")

        Try
            Dim objData As [Object] = sendData
            Dim byData As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(objData.ToString())
            If m_clientSocket IsNot Nothing Then
                m_clientSocket.Send(byData)
            End If

            write_log(Now.ToString & " : " & sendData & vbCrLf, "sendData", "sendData")
        Catch se As SocketException
            logstr = se.Message
            write_log(logstr, "WaitForData", "waitfordata")
        End Try

    Else

        receiveData = state.sb.ToString()


        If receiveData <> "" Then
            write_log(Now.ToString & " : " & receiveData & vbCrLf, "receiveData2", "receiveData2")
        End If


    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You should share some code.

Comment: Both state.sb.Append() and Me.lsBulk.Items.Insert() look like good places to leak memory.  Very unlikely this code can operate correctly and the code was hacked to try to get it to work, thus producing the leak.  You get an *arbitrary* number of bytes in the callback, nothing resembling an "item" that you can add to a list.

Comment: thank you @HansPassant I really appreciate your reply. But I am quite new in this Socket programming so I would appreciate most if you explain in a little bit detail for me on how I can clear the buffer? thank you

Comment: Sending a "message" over a socket requires telling the receiver how long the message is so it *knows* how many bytes to receive for a message.  You must therefore send the length first.

Comment: Hi, I am so sorry I haven't seen your message before. As I got another reply at the below comment I thought that is the one. Any ways, thank you so much for your reply. Actually I am sending buffersize 10024 in BeginReceive() so is it the one you are saying as length? I am so sorry if I sound silly but I am really so new in socket and also in string builder so quite confused. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation `BeginReceive` "begins to asynchronously receive data from a connected `Socket`.". So in normal language: start receiving data while continuing execution of the program.

In the documentation from `EndReceive` "the callback method must accept the IAsyncResult returned by the BeginConnect method as a parameter." and "After obtaining the Socket, you can call the EndConnect method to successfully complete the connection attempt."

And also: "The asynchronous BeginReceive operation must be completed by calling the EndReceive method. Typically, the method is invoked by the callback delegate."

So yes, you have to call `EndReceive` to get the results of the `BeginReceive`.

Also, as answer to your second question: "To obtain the received data, call the `AsyncState` method of the `IAsyncResult`, and extract the buffer contained in the resulting state object." So the result is buffered in the `IAsyncResult` object. Extract it from there and get rid of the object to let GC collect it.

Source: [BeginReceive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginreceive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [EndReceive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7wtt64b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [IAsyncResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: thank you so much for your nice explanation. It helped to understand better.

Comment: But I have a question. Does it clears the buffer every time I call the EndReceive() method?

Comment: Thank you so much for the update. I got the point but still I am having trouble on how to extract the buffer from AsyncState method and how can I give this to GC for handling. I would really appreciate if you can give some example. Thank you.

Comment: 1. I don't really get the problem, but it seems to me you convert the buffer to string and then to byte[]. This does not make sense to me. 2. release all references to the object and the GC will collect it.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply ok I will try your solutions. Actually my problem is when the software is running it is allocating huge physical memory of the system for example: 20 GB but not suddenly. It first allocates 2GB then 3GB and then so on until we restart it. So I think the buffer is not getting cleared that's why it is allocating so much of memory. But as I don't have enough knowledge on Socket and buffer so I am seeking for help from experts like you. Thank you.

Comment: @barsan: Did you set the `size` on your request? It is the third parameter on the BeginReceive. If you keep reading, you should leave it somewhere instead of memory, on disk for example. Use a [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx) to write to disk.

Comment: Yes I have set the size of buffer as 10024. Is that ok?